# Estrutura de repetição que compara valores iguais e printe a correspondência

Tags: typescript, algoritmo

Tenho dois arrays:

**operador.tabela_perm** possui ids de tela e o array **telas** possui além do id, o nome das telas.

Preciso criar uma estrutura de repetição que compare os dois arrays e printe o nome da tela.

Tentei algo como:

Meu array **operador.tabela_perm:**

```
(4) [1, 3, 9, 5]
0: 1
1: 3
2: 9
3: 5
length: 4
```

Meu array **telas:**

```
0: {id: 1, nome_tela: "Cadastrar Operador", created_at: null}
1: {id: 2, nome_tela: "Tipo do Produto", created_at: null}
2: {id: 3, nome_tela: "Produtos", created_at: null}
3: {id: 4, nome_tela: "Custos Fixos", created_at: null}
4: {id: 5, nome_tela: "Custos Variáveis", created_at: null}
5: {id: 6, nome_tela: "Custos Extras", created_at: null}
6: {id: 7, nome_tela: "Listagem dos Custos Fixos", created_at: null}
```

O array operador.tabela_perm possui como valores os IDS das telas.
O array telas possui id e nome, preciso printar o nome das telas que existem na tabela_perm.

```
    for(let i=0; i<this.operador.tabela_perm.length; i++){
      for(let j=0;j<this.operador.tabela_perm.length; j++){
        if(this.operador.tabela_perm[i] == this.telas[j].id){
          console.log(this.telas[j].nome_tela)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Precisa de contexto maior. Pra mim está tudo ok.

Comment: Dessa maneira alguns nomes não são printados, mesmo quando nos dois arrays tenham o mesmo ID

Comment: Precisa de um [Exemplo minimo completo e verificavel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para que seja facil de ver o problema e apresentar uma solução

Comment: Fiz uma edição na publicação

Comment: De acordo com o exemplo de dados de entrada que deu, qual seria a saída que esperava ver ?

Comment: Cadastrar Operador, Produtos, Custos variáveis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que está acontecendo é que no seu segundo `for`, a condição de parada é `this.operador.tabela_perm.length`, que no eu exemplo é 4, então seu `if` só vai comparar até a posição 4 do array de telas, seu código deve ser assim:

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.operador.tabela_perm.length; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < this.telas.length; j++) {
        if(this.operador.tabela_perm[i] == this.telas[j].id) {
            console.log(this.telas[j].nome_tela)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como você está utilizando Typescript, seria bacana você utilizar os recursos dele, como por exemplo os [Arrow Functions](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html), segue um exemplo de como ficaria a mesma solução acima citada.

```
tabela_perm.forEach((perm)=>{
  console.log(telas.find((telaName)=> telaName.id == perm).nome_tela)
})
```